# Is there a way to always execute some code before Exit Function in VBScript

Tags: function, vbscript, exit, qtp

I would like to write a function in which there are multiple "Exit Function" statements. Is there a way for me to make sure some clean up code is alway run before doing the exit function?

Here is what I'm actually trying to do, I want to set a standard in my test automation project, that certain function should run before the code of any function begins and run another function before exiting out of the function. Is there any simple way of doing this?

Comment: One possible solution I could think of is wrapping the original function in a different function and write required code before and after that actual function call. This becomes cumbersome after some time if there are many functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrapper class of Ekkehard.Horner is very usefull if you have stuff to do that can be out of scope of the function, like a stopwatch, a runstack viewer or an exception trapper on the err object. But when you have things to do inside the scope of the function and the wrapper class renders useless, you could consider using the `Do Loop While False` pattern:

```
Function DoSomeMessyStuff()
    Do
        call doStuff()
        If somecondition Then Exit Do
        call doMoreStuff()
        If somecondition Then Exit Do
        call doEvenMoreStuff()
        If somecondition Then Exit Do
        call andEvenMoreStuffHere()
    Loop While False ' Always exits

    ' Finally: 
    call cleanUpTheMess()

End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

As wrapping functions in functions isn't easy in VBScript (expect problems of parameter passing), you should use a class:

```
Class cWrap
  Private m_sName
  Public Function init(s)
    Set init = Me
    m_sName  = s
    WScript.Echo "*** enter", m_sName
  End Function ' init
  Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    WScript.Echo "*** leave", m_sName
  End Sub ' Class_Terminate
End Class ' cWrap

Function f1(n)
  f1 = "f1 called"
  Dim o : Set o = New cWrap.init("f1")
End Function ' f1

Function f2(n)
  f2 = "f2 called"
  Dim o : Set o = New cWrap.init("f2")
End Function ' f2
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the `Set o = New cWrap.init()` line should be one of the first lines of the function (that wasn't obvious to me).  By the way, you can also use `Class_Initialize` to run code before the rest of the function runs.

Comment: Thanks for the good answers, I guess I may have to live with the limitations for now.